# Spring Data - at least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have the following JPA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT e.id "
            + "FROM schema.entity e "
            + "WHERE e.number = :number", nativeQuery = true)
Long getEntityByNumber(@Param("number") String number);

}
```

And I have the following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the code for Schema for which you have created this JpaRepository?

Comment: I highly doubt that `Long` is a managed entity.

Comment: So what if I don`t want to have managed entities for my db objects ? I guess spring JPA cannot handle simple native queries without managed entities ?

Comment: If you don't want managed entities, don't use JPA. Use plain JDBC instead.

Comment: It needs to be managed - whats the issue mapping schema.entity to a JPA object? You could add your query as a nativequery on another JPA object - but it would confuse your design

Comment: If you want to avoid JPA, you might want to look into using the good old [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) class. Still easier than plain JDBC, but no JPA overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create @Entity instead using Long class.

like:

```
@Entity
public class MyLong {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private Long long;

}
```

Comment: - would mind taking a look at this -  [JPA metamodel must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274742/error-creating-bean-with-name-jpamappingcontext-jpa-metamodel-must-not-be-emp)