# Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': JPA metamodel must not be empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-3

While migrating from spring batch 4 to 5 (actually spring boot 2.6.6 to 3.1.3 upgrade), i came across several issues which are [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271554/spring-batch-required-a-bean-named-datasource-that-could-not-be-found).

Now I am stuck at error - `Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': JPA metamodel must not be empty`. (I don't use any DB features like monitors/status tables etc of spring batch.)

The top few line of stacktrace are -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': JPA metamodel must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```

What does above error mean and how can i solve it. (It seems to be more of spring data jpa issue then spring batch issue).

I went through other SOF post for this error but nothing solved my problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is a prod blocker for me.

**edit 1 - build.gradle is as below -**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
}

dependencies {
    implementation **couple of internal project.**

    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${Version.LOMBOK}"
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${Version.LOMBOK}"

    configurations {
        all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        all*.exclude module : 'logback-classic'
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"

    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${Version.LOGBACK}"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:${Version.LOGBACK}"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${Version.GOOGLE_GUAVA}"
    implementation "com.h2database:h2:2.2.224"
    implementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:${Version.MSSQL_SERVER}"
    implementation "de.siegmar:logback-gelf:${Version.LOGBACK_GELF}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:${Version.POSTGRESQL}"


    testImplementation project(":esl-store-metadata").sourceSets.main.output

    testImplementation "de.siegmar:logback-gelf:${Version.LOGBACK_GELF}"
    testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${Version.LOMBOK}"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:${Version.SPRING_CLOUD}"
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') { exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine' }
}
```

And right, like suggested by @M.Deinum, spring data rest is coming from a dependent project which is using netflix graphql libs.
[image]

Comment: You have Spring Data related classes on your class path, which required some context. If you don't use Spring Data why is it on your class path.

Comment: @M.Deinum - right `spring data jpa` is in build.gradle. The previous dev's have used stuff like `import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest` in the project. So now I am not able to remove the dependency from the project. :-(. Is there anything else I can do ??

Comment: @M.Deinum  PageRequest is coming because it's part of `public abstract class AbstractPagingItemReader<T> extends AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader<T>
  implements InitializingBean {`  as my class does this -> `public class ProductPublisherJobPageReader extends AbstractPagingItemReader<Product> {
`

Comment: The error is from Spring Dat REST (read the error message).

Comment: If you aren't using JPA why is the dependency there, if you do, why isn't it detecting your entities. From the several questions you asked I wonder what manual dependency management you are doing and manual configuration as well. As most of this should  be straight forward, but it feels like your project tries to outsmart Spring Boot and the auto configuration and dependency management.

Comment: @M.Deinum - i think the dependency on JPA is because we are extending `AbstractPagingItemReader`. We are not reading from DB but from a rest service and the paging concept we use to read rest service mimics the paging concept of DB table. So the extension from `AbstractPagingItemReader`. I don't think now I can remove `JPA` from project because of above reason even though we don't involve any DB. Does this answer. ??

Comment: Read, please read... **The error is from Spring Dat REST**. I'm voring to close this as clearly there is too little information in this question to answer it. As I stated, imho your project tries to outsmart the dependency management and configuration of Spring Boot. Don't.

Comment: @M.Deinum - i am adding the build.gradle. so please hold on. I got you point, but i am not using spring data Rest in the project or build.gradle.  If it's comming from dependent projects, i am checking.

Comment: @M.Deinum - i did try `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)` as for sure i don't need spring data rest on this project. But it did not help atall.

Comment: Well apparently you do as you are using graphql from Netflix which requires it.